# How to change horizontal scroll bar width in Material Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Is it possible to change the thickness of the horizontal scroll bar of [Material-Table](https://material-table.com/#/)? I've tried adding the `scrollBarWidth` property and the `scrollPadding` property to the `style` prop in the table component, but it didn't work. Is it possible to change the width at all?

[image]

Comment: Mike K Did you find any solution for this .Please share.

Comment: @Delta Well yes, but actually no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63407496/2891356

Answer (score 1):

Setting the **doubleHorizontalScroll** 'options' property to **true** worked for me. [Reference](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props)

```
options = {{
    doubleHorizontalScroll: true
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it, via inspect elements, and find the specific class

Example
[image]

by putting css in your material table class in elements; you'll see it early the result without reloading the pages .

and if you put it to the code use :host ::ng-deep to reflect your changes.

Example

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {
    min-width: 112px;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to my original question, but I managed to set the width of the horizontal scroll bar by overriding the styles of all scrollbars on the page.

Anyway, looks something like this,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px; /* <-- This sets the thickness of the VERTICAL scrollbar */
  height: 20px; /* <-- This sets the thickness of the HORIZONTAL scrollbar */
}
```

I should note, that this doesn't work in Firefox or IE/Edge.

[image: Edit nervous-glitter-1j0xc]

Answer (score 0):

Adding this css to the div wrapping my MaterialTable removed the preset scrollbar and replaced it with the styled scrollbar.

```
* {
overflow-y: clip !important;
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

}